# Wordpress swapping div content with php do_shortcode

Tags: jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I have a script with in my wordpress header. I want to dynamically load a form into a container with clicking a button. There are two forms total, and of course one button per form.

When I store the do_shortcode function into a php variable, store the php variable into a jquery variable, the shortcode executes. When i change the html value of the container with the variable echoing the php do_shortcode variable, it does NOT render the form, but only the shortcode value. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php $cf7Shortcode = do_shortcode( "[contact-form-7 id='11' title='form']" ); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var form1 = <?php echo $cf7Shortcode ?>,
        form2 ='test',

        button1 = $('#btn1'),   
        button2 = $('#btn2')

        formContainer = $('#form-container');


    button1.on("click", function(){
        formContainer.html(form1);
    });

    button2.on("click", function(){
        formContainer.html(form2);
    });

});


</script>
```

Comment: This should be done by using ajax, and passing the request to a controller that executes the shortcode form and sends it back as a response.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ohgodwhy. Can you direct me to a resource so I can figure it out?

Comment: I'll add an answer with the solution using ajax. I'm feeling spunky. Give me a few minutes, I'm eating lunch, so check back in 15-30

Answer (score 2):

In your theme's functions.php file, we'll want to declare the ajax function we wish to run.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_contact_form', 'get_contact_form');
add_action('wp_admin_ajax_get_contact_form', 'get_contact_form');
```

This will register your ajax hook for the function `get_contact_form`

```
function get_contact_form(){
    if(isset($_GET['form_id'])):
        echo do_shortcode( "[contact-form-7 id='$_GET['form_id']' title='form']" );
    endif;
    exit(); //need this, or you'll have issues with getting '1' back as a value
}
```

Now when you make an ajax request with `action: get_contact_form`, it will attempt to run the above function. Since we aren't passing parameters into the function, we're going to check if `form_id` was set, if it was, we'll return the shortcode. We have to exit regardless.

Let's set up our ajax call.

```
buttons.click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl, //global variable provided by WP
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'action' : 'get_contact_form',
            'form_id' : $(this).data('form')
        },
        success: function(data){
            formContainer.html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The key pieces above are `$(this).data('form')`, which is a `data attribute`. It looks like you have control of the markup, so add reference to the ID of the form you want to get to your HTML, like this ->

```
data-form="11"
```

The second key piece is `success:function(data){`, when the ajax request is successful, it will take the data returned and make it the HTML of the `formContainer`. In our case, it will be the form.

Finally, instead of using `id's`, use a `class` for your buttons.

```
class="ajax-form-button"
```

Then instead of `var button1 = / button 2 =`, just do `buttons = $('.ajax-form-button')`. Then we don't have to make a bunch of click/ajax functions, because we're allowing the logic to be handled by the `data-form` attribute. This will keep the code minimal and reusable.

I don't think I've forgotten anything here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the in-depth response! I am very new to ajax, and have a couple of questions to get it working - if you don't mind.

Do I put the get_contact_form() function within the functions.php? I am getting a PHP error because the line:
echo do_shortcode( "[contact-form-7 id='$_GET['form_id']' title='form']" )

It has two sets of [ ]. Sublime text highlights it in pink.

Also, I got the console log error "ajaxurl is not defined wordpress", but resolved it by using: <?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>

Comment: That's weird. `ajaxurl` is defined in version `3.x`..so unless you're using 2, I don't see that being an issue. If the do shortcode function throws that error, then make the string outside of it, `var $form_id = $_GET['form_id']` and then make `id='$form_id'`.

Comment: Still get an error:

`<?php 
function get_contact_form(){

    if(isset($_GET['form_id'])):
    var $form_id = $_GET['form_id'];
        echo do_shortcode( "[contact-form-7 id='$form_id' title='form']" );
    endif;
    exit(); //need this, or you'll have issues with getting '1' back as a value
} 
 ?>`